# firefox not adding/removing class on checked/unchecked checkbox input

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox

Hi I've got a couple of instance where the other dev (doing the CSS/HTML) has coded some options as checkboxes where the user would click/tap them to 'check' them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.terms input:checkbox').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
     }
  });
});
```

This works fine in Chrome, but doesn't do *anything* in Firefox (lastest on OSX)

Any reasons? What have I done horribly wrong here?

EDIT: Sorry for not providing  any HTML :-/

```
 <div class="terms">
   <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="Acepto las condiciones" />
   <p class="checkbox"></p>
   <p>Acepto las condiciones <a title="Términos y condiciones" href="static.html">?</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your html as well ?

Comment: Since you are using `toggleClass` why do you need `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gJ9fC/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");

  });
});
```

Since you use a toggle, you don't need to check if your checkbox is checked.
When you use a toggle, jquery removes the class or adds, depens on what you asking!

O and i removed the .terms because you don't have it. you can use .subproducts

Comment: Hi, this works brilliantly. I've edited the code and fired up Firefox and it still doesn't work. Even though the jsfiddle does? Could the error be in how the CSS is written to cause this?

Comment: Hmm i think more in how your jquery/js code is written, prob there is a fault, look the errorconsole of firefox to detect. if none put all your jquery in a JShint ;)

Answer (score 1):

With small changes in your jQuery, you can achieve what you want to do. And do not forget to add `.checked` class in your css file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.terms input:checkbox').on('change', function(){          
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");   
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/WqnpJ/1/)

Another example using `label` tag. What i believe is it is more convenient for user experience.

[Example using label](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/WqnpJ/3/)